# How to update rails page content using AJAX when select changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a @course form that belongs_to a lesson, and each lesson has_many gradable_items.  The lesson_id is selected via a drop menu.  When the user changes the lesson select, the nested inputs representing each gradable_item must be updated.  This is doable with a page refresh and passing the lesson_id as url param...so, that that lessons gradable_items exist as nested inputs, where they can then be graded (and saved as graded_items).  But, seems AJAX is perfect for this.

The code below is not working...and I'm wondering what I'm missing.

- course_lesson_id - the select menu where the lesson is chosen
- "/gradable_items_input?lesson=#{el.val()}" - the url to the gradable_items_inputs.js.erb template that ajax should inject into the view where the function call was originated.
- gradable_items_container - is where AJAX should inject the code returned from the template

The alert() triggers as expected, and the class is added but not removed...since I never get success.

What I am expecting to occur is this:
The select menu is changed, this triggers the function.  The function grabs the id of the selected item in the lesson_id menu and then goes to the gradable_items_inputs url using the lesson_id as a url param.  When this template is accessed it queries the db in the Course controller using the gradable_items_inputs action.  This query uses url param for the lesson_id to filter records and populate the gradable_items_inputs.js.erb file.  Then, when success...AJAX puts the code from the gradable_items_inputs template inside the div with id #gradable_items_container.

Is my thought process here flawed?  I guess the answer must be yes...since it is not working.

```
  jQuery ->
    el = $("#course_lesson_id")
    el.on "change", ->
    $.ajax "/gradable_items_inputs?lesson=#{el.val()}",
    beforeSend: ->
      $("#ajax_tell").addClass "is-fetching"

    success: (response) ->
      $("#gradable_items_container").html(response)

    complete: (response) ->
      $("#ajax_tell").removeClass "is-fetching"

    error: ->
      $("#{ajax_tell}").html "<p>ERROR</p>"

    timeout: 3000
    alert "test"
```

## The gradable_items_inputs.js.erb file:

```
  $('#gradable_items_container').html('

<% @gradable_items.each do |gradable_item| %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :graded_items do |graded_item| %> 

    <p>
    <%= gradable_item.name %>
    <%= graded_item.input :gradable_item_id, input_html: { value: gradable_item.id, }, as: :hidden %>
    <%= graded_item.input :grade, collection: gradescales(@course), label: false %>
   </p>

  <% end %> 
    <% end %>

  ');
```

## courses_controller.rb

```
  def gradable_items_inputs
     @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:lesson])

     respond_to do |format|
        format.js { }
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
dataType:'script'
```

To the Ajax call params. This will ensure that the request format is js.

The best way to debug an Ajax call is to monitor it from both sides. Look at your rails server log to see how the request is received and the use your browser network inspector to see the response.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you haven't created the routes for gradable_item_inputs.

check routes.rb, must have the following code:

```
 resources :courses do
    collection do
      get gradable_item_inputs
    end
  end
```

Comment: I updated my code above.  Thanks, joreal...there was a routing issue.  Thanks Moran...I added the dataType as you suggested.